# On Mac, where to find the audio files of the sounds in the native Clock app?

Tags: macos, mac, audio

I am trying to add my own custom sounds that I can use for Timer within the Clock app. I'm guessing if I find where the audio files are located, I can just add my own audio file and use it as an option. I am on MacOS Sonoma.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The sounds are stored in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Ringtones/`. As this is on the System volume which is protected from any modification by the user via [SSV](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secd698747c9/web), there is no way to add your own sounds to that directory.

PS: Also, the application would need to be written in a way to automatically pick up new tracks.

Comment: Before Catalina you could do this by replacing an existing wav file, keeping the known name. It would never read any new names.